# Upload zip files to service for user download

Tags: node.js, file-upload, express, amazon-s3, zip

I have an express (node.js) application that creates mp3 files for a user and stores them in a folder on the server.

The server's file structure looks like this:

```
data/
  id#/
    song1.mp3
    song2.mp3
    song3.mp3
  id#/
    song1.mp3
    song2.mp3
    song3.mp3
  ...
```

I want to create zip files and download links for the folder and email users their zip file. Each folder is named using an id# and corresponds to a user.

I want to use an external service (such as s3) to store and handle the downloads of the files.

How would I zip up the files and send them to the service and create download links? Which services should I look into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `child_process` module to run a zip command in the background (this example is for say if you're on Linux, you can modify it to suit windows)

This just handles the zip process, then you can respond with the link to download the file:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var currentWorkingDirectory = '/data', // Folder that contains the sub folders of id#/
    folderToZip             = 'id123123',  // Subfolder name id#, e.g. id123123
    tmpFolderForZips        = '/tmp/', // Folder to store the zip files in
    execString              = "zip -r " + tmpFolderForZips + folderToZip + ".zip " + folderToZip; // Tidy string to put it all together
console.log(execString);

var child = exec(execString, { cwd: currentWorkingDirectory });

child.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
})

child.on('close', function() {
    // respond with download link to zip file
    console.log('Done Zipping');
});
```

Make sure you `apt-get install zip`

Comment: How would I upload this to a file server and make it downloadable from here?